# How to post an array object in ajax call in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, post

I have below JSON response, I have to post that in my ajax call but i don't know how to do that.

JSON response:

```
{
    "iASensorTypePresetRequest": [{
            "sensorPresetTypeId": "1",
            "min": "30",
            "max": "50"
        }, {
            "sensorPresetTypeId": "3",
            "min": "1",
            "max": "200"
        }, {
            "sensorPresetTypeId": "5",
            "min": "true",
            "max": "NA"
        }, {
            "sensorPresetTypeId": "6",
            "min": "false",
            "max": "NA"
        }

    ]
}
```

I have below code:

```
 var formData = $scope.PresetObject;

 var reqHeader = {
     method: 'POST',
    url: getAPI_URL('221') + $scope.selectedUseCase,
    data: formData
 };

ajaxService.AjaxCall(SuccessFunction, ErrorFunction, reqHeader);
```

I have posted objects but i have to post that in array that is 'iASensorTypePresetRequest'

I have written service 'ajaxService' and written functions in it 'SuccessFunction' in success function i have called $http service also I have written error function and calling 'AjaxCall' function of service from controller.

My question is How to post an array containing objects in ajax call?

Comment: Just stringify it `JSON.stringify` and then POST it with that data

Answer (score -1):

I use the $http service when communicating with the backend. I recommend placing all your backend connectivity into a service.  I call mine datacontext.

this is the link to the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation

```
 var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

If your api is RESTful you can use the $resource factory.

Comment: You should describe what you're actually doing instead of just saying 'I use the ....'. Also you should describe why you are recommending to use a service for backend connections. And at least you should describe why this should solve the problem.

Comment: [The $http service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Creating a service to wrap all data communication to the server allows you to centralize this communication and make maintenance easier.